# Unable to use AfterReadEvent when MultiRecordEngine is used

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I am using `MultiRecordEngine` for my delimiter ('|') input file.  As I need to check/validate that certain fields not exceeding certain sizes and some field must contain either "YES" or "NO" value.  However, I am not able to include `AfterReadEvent` even I follow the example from the filehelper website.

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow, Please add your code! Also please explain what happens that make u not able? Is there any error or what? please provide more information, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the class definitions from [the MultiRecordEngine example here](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/Advanced/MultiRecordEngine/), the following example demonstrates a working `AfterReadEvent`:

```
public class Program
{
    private static int _EventCount = 0;
    public static void Test_Import()
    {
        var str = @"10248|VINET|5|04071996|01081996|16071996|3|32.38" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "10249|TOMSP|6|05071996|16081996|10071996|1|11.61" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "ALFKI;Alfreds Futterkiste;Maria Anders;Sales Representative;Obere Str. 57;Berlin;Germany" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "ANATR;Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados;Ana Trujillo;Owner;Avda. de la Constitución 2222;México D.F.;Mexico" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "10250 |HANAR|4|08071996|05081996|12071996|2|65.83" + Environment.NewLine
                    + "10111314012345";

        var engine = new MultiRecordEngine(typeof(Orders),
            typeof(Customer),
            typeof(SampleType));

        engine.RecordSelector = new RecordTypeSelector(CustomSelector);

        engine.AfterReadRecord += Engine_AfterReadRecord;

        var records = engine.ReadString(str);
        Assert.AreEqual(6, records.Count());
        Assert.AreEqual(6, _EventCount);
    }

    private static void Engine_AfterReadRecord(EngineBase engine, AfterReadEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        // Increment the event counter
        _EventCount++;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test_Import();
        Console.WriteLine("OK");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and code.  I am able to compile and run my application now.  Are you able to show me how can I read the values from two different record structures?

Comment: By the way, is this (engine.ErrorManager.ErrorMode = ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue;) advisable for MultiRecordEngine ?   I keep getting error for one of the records.

Comment: Sure, `SaveAndContinue` is a good way of handling errors. After your import, you can enumerate through errors and display any error messages. See [here](https://www.filehelpers.net/example/ErrorHandling/ErrorMode.SaveAndContinue/)